# jQuery selector for empty value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How could I create a selector to use with `.is()` function in jQuery that represents the following expressions:

```
$('[name="Person[firstName]"]').val() === ''; // true
$('[name="Person[lastName]"]').val() === ''; // false
```

With this HTML context

```
<input name="Person[firstName]" value="" >
  <foo bar="true" />
</input>

<input name="Person[lastName]" value="ABCDEFGH" />
```

**:empty Selector**  Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

```
 $('[name="Person[firstName]"]').is(':empty'); // false
 $('[name="Person[lastName]"]').is(':empty'); // true
```

Another try

```
$('[name="Person[firstName]"]').is('[value=""]'); // true
$('[name="Person[lastName]"]').is('[value=""]'); // true
```

**Note:** This is a question for knowledge purposes - and **.is()** must be used in this solution.

**@edit** http://jsfiddle.net/2CzWu/2/

It must return false on both expressions

Comment: Thas not the point. It's only a example to avoid anwsers like this http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Comment: @Allyson, *and `.is()` must be used in this solution.* Why? Using `is()` seems counter-productive to the results you want to achieve.

Comment: Your statement that `$('[name="Person[lastName]"]').is('[value=""]')` returns `true` does not seem to be the case. The code in that block seems to work as expected for me. http://jsfiddle.net/2CzWu/1/

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I believe the OP wants to create a boolean expression to emulate the first code block using the `.is()` method.

Comment: @RubenInfante You are right! The statement are working thanks! I will close this question

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I miss a typo in my project

Comment: @RubenInfante Ops maybe it's really wrong. When I edited the firstName and execute this code in jsfiddle the result it's not right - try input some text and execute this selector. http://jsfiddle.net/2CzWu/2/ must return `false` on both

Comment: @RagenDazs @pswg I've reworked my answer, I think it now clearly answers the question and does work with `$.is` and `:not`. Take a look at it.

Comment: It's not so much an issue of `<input>` being a self-closing tag in that it's a void element. Even if you didn't close the tag (because HTML doesn't even require you to do so), it would still not be able to contain any other elements.

Answer (score 5):

The reason `:empty` doesn't work is because it's looking for nodes without child nodes, which is not what you are looking for.

`$.is("[value='']")` will only work with values that were set in the HTML initially, not as you update it whether through a script or by the UI. That is because the attribute selector looks at `Node.getAttribute('value') === ''` [and the XML attribute is not updated when the DOM object is](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/5Eum7/), but the DOM property `HTMLInputElement.value` does.

[So what we really need is a custom pseudo selector that looks at the value DOM property](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/2CzWu/8/) and [it's pretty simple to implement](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html). It works with `$.is` and with `:not()`

```
$.expr[':'].emptyVal = function(obj){
   return obj.value === '';
};

var $firstName = $('[name="Person[firstName]"]');

$firstName.val('AAAA');

$('input:emptyVal').size(); // 2
$('input:not(emptyVal)').size(); // 0
$firstName.is('input:emptyVal'); // false
$firstName.is('input:not(:emptyVal)'); // true
```

Comment: Yes I miss a typo on my project :(

Comment: Ops maybe it's really wrong. When I edited the firstName and execute this code the result it's not right

Comment: @AllysondePaula That's because `jQuery.val('aaaa')` doesn't set the `value` attribute on the node. If you use `jQuery.attr('value', 'aaaa')` it will work http://jsfiddle.net/2CzWu/3/ I'm afraid there's not much you can do about that